# How best to sum 2 columns and update 3rd column with sum?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for the best way to add 2 or more columns in a SQL Server table and update another column with there sum.

Yes, I know this is a dumb thing to do and calculations should be done at time of transaction but I am modifying an existing table where the data in a column now needs to be more detailed but numerous processes will still use the column value.

For example, a column name is TotalDailyMiles and numerous processes access and use that field. Now more detail is needed. 2 columns need to be added to the table TotalAMMiles and TotalPMMiles. These 2 columns will sum to the existing column. Changing all the processes that access the TotalDailyMiles column to use the 2 new columns instead is not an option. The data for the new columns in old records does not exist so the value for columns holding the sum of the 2 new columns cannot be based on the 2 new columns in old records because in old records the new column values will be 0, or maybe null but I'm leaning toward 0 so I can set the new columns as Not Null.

I'm thinking of using a trigger to update the column holding the sum based on the new columns changing but I'm hoping one of you smart people have a better option.

Comment: triggers are definitely the way to go here.  I would be afraid of two zeroes in the split columns and a total that does not match.  maybe at least fill in one with the value and the other with 0 so any new code will also work.

Comment: @Randy imho, triggers are NOT the way to go. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about treating the existing column as its own value (which will be 0 in future rows), adding the two new columns, and then creating a calculated column with the same name as the old Total? Something like this (I'm assuming a data type of `decimal(7, 2)` but of course use what you have, though I hope it's not `float`):

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.Miles.TotalDailyMiles', 'DailyMiles';
ALTER TABLE dbo.Miles ADD COLUMN AMMiles decimal(7, 2) NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT DF_Miles_AMMiles DEFAULT (0);
ALTER TABLE dbo.Miles ADD COLUMN PMMiles decimal(7, 2) NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT DF_Miles_PMMiles DEFAULT (0);
ALTER TABLE dbo.Miles ADD COLUMN TotalDailyMiles
   AS (DailyMiles + AMMiles + PMMiles) PERSISTED;
```

Some possible housekeeping that might be needed on the DailyMiles column, too:

```
-- if not already NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE dbo.Miles ALTER COLUMN AMMiles decimal(7, 2) NOT NULL;
-- if not already defaulting to 0
ALTER TABLE dbo.Miles ADD
   CONSTRAINT DF_Miles_DailyMiles DEFAULT (0) FOR DailyMiles;
```

You could additionally add a constraint that either `DailyMiles` must be 0, or `AMMiles` and `PMMiles` must both be 0:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Miles ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Miles_DailyOrAMPM
   CHECK (DailyMiles = 0 OR (AMMiles = 0 AND PMMiles = 0));
```

As long as consumers of the data don't try to update the `TotalDailyMiles` column, you've solved your problem handily.

Comment: +1. Not sure what happens if one the added columns has Nulls. You may have to edit the calculation to use `COALESCE(col, 0.0)`

Comment: this is nice. but I would still go with a trigger - also - i would feel bad for some future coder who sees all these columns and has to figure out what to insert in which column in either case.

Comment: @Randy - that's where business rules and documentation come in. If the future coder has no clue what column to insert to, he has no business working with the table. If coders are this fragile, wouldn't the mere presentation of the three columns you proposed also be confusing? The questions of what on earth are `AMMiles` and `PMMiles` are bound to arise in any case? And what if, in your scenario, things get out of sync and they mistakenly run the code `UPDATE dbo.Miles SET TotalDailyMiles = TotalAMMiles + TotalPMMiles`? After full consideration, I still recommend this.

Comment: @ypercube In my solution the added columns are specified `NOT NULL`.

Comment: @ErikE Yes, it was more a comment to the OP than you (he mentions Nulls several times.)

Comment: @ypercube - Thank you for the comments and discussion. As someone relatively new to the field, I found your comments and discussion educational and interesting. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Randy - Thank you for the comments and discussion. As someone relatively new to the field, I found your comments and discussion educational and interesting. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @ErikE - Thank you for the comments and discussion. As someone relatively new to the field, I found your comments and discussion educational and interesting. It is very much appreciated.